# Solve a combinatorial problem using a probabilistic approach.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, approximation

Consider two arrays of length 100, among those 10 entries are 1 and rest are 0.

I want to add these two arrays co-ordinate wise such that there is no 2 in the sum.

Number of such arrays will be $N_1= \binom{100}{10} \times \binom{90}{10}$. Instead of combinatorial approach, I want to take a probabilistic approach. Any co-ordinate of any array is zero with probability 0.9. Thus probability that sum of two co-ordinates is 0 or 1 is $p=(0.9)^2+2\times 0.9\times 0.1$. So I calculate ﻿number of arrays for which sum is 0/1 in each co-ordinate is

$N_2= (\binom{100}{10})^2 \times p^{100}$. But it does not match with $N_1$. I understand it is not correct to assume independence among the co-ordinate sum. But can we find good approximation using a probabilistic approach? Actually, instead of 0 or 1, I want to include -1 also in the arrays. Also I start with 3 arrays instead of 2 arrays and want to calculutale number of arrays with give binary sum in the co-ordinate wise. It seems combinatorially problem becomes dificult. So I want probabilistic approach, which can give good approximation. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in a probabilistic way, you can't take $0.9$ as the probability. The correct value will be

Pr $= \frac{90}{100}\frac{89}{99}\frac{88}{98} ...\frac{81}{91}$

which will make the answers tally, but I don't know if this will help you.

**PS:**

The first array could have the $1's$ in any $10$ places, and the probability that the second array is aligned appropriately is given by the expression, indicating a probability of $\approx 0.33$ for "second arrays" that are aligned in the desired manner for **each** of the possible first arrays

**PPS**

I have worked it out for your three arrays. Denoting $-1, 0,1$ as $N,O,P$ respectively, there can be various favorable alignments looking vertically that sum to $0, \;or\; 1$, viz

$NOP\; 6$ permutations
$NPP\; 3$ permutations
$OOO\; 1$ permutation, and
$OOP\;3$ permutations

P(a random vertical slice of the array sums to $0$ or $1$)
= $\frac{1}{100^3}(6\cdot5\cdot85\cdot15 + 3\cdot5\cdot15^2+ 85^3+ 3\cdot85^2\cdot15) = \frac{7847}{8000}, \approx 0.98$

Thus by linearity of expectation, expected # of co-ordinates summing to $0$ or $1 = 100*0.98 = 98$

This is happening as the overwhelming majority  are $O's$

I checked that the probabilities taking **all** possible configurations [does sum up to $1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5B1%2F100%5E3%5D%5B5%5E3%2B++3%285%5E2*80+%2B5%5E2*15+%2B5*80%5E2%29+%2B6*5*80*15+%2B3*5*15%5E2%2B80%5E3%2B3%2880%5E2*15%2B80*15%5E2%29%2B15%5E3%5D)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will you kindly explain how this will match with combinatorial value?

Comment: I have added a PS.

Comment: Thank you so much. But it is not clear to me how to include -1 in the count. I am thinking of the Markov chain idea without success.

Comment: It is not clear to me how $-1$ is going to be used, and the objective of the third array.

Comment: My final problem is to use 3 arrays with 0,1 and -1.

Comment: 0,1,-1 in *each* array ? And then how are they to be aligned ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. Yes, 0,1 & -1 in each array. 80 many 0, 15 many 1 & 5 many -1 in each array.

Comment: And co-ordinate wise, what should be the sum ?

Comment: It should be 0 or 1.

Comment: PPS solving your $3$ array problem. Have a good day :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your hard work. So if we consider arrays with 0 and 1 case, probability will be (1/100^2)*(90^2+2*90*10)=0.99 if there are 90 many 0's and 10 many 1's.  From this how can we find required number of configurations binomial(100,10)*binomial(90,10)?

Comment: In the two array case, I computed  the probability that these two arrays were *entirely* properly aligned as per the stipulation. In the three array case I computed the *number* of co-ordinates ( vertical slices) that would be properly aligned. Actually, I'm not too clear about what exactly  is wanted,  not knowing the background of the application, so I've given two different approaches. I can convert between the two.

Comment: In three array case we have  (factorial(100)/(factorial(85) * factorial(15) * factorial(5)))^3 many options. Among those, I want to find number of choices so that all 100 co-ordinate sum (vertical slice) is 0/1. You have proved one random co-ordinate sum is 0/1 with probability 0.98. So all will be 0/1 with probability 0.98^100, assuming independence. From this can we estimate the required number of choices? Thanks a lot for your support.